# Cross Domain Request to localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

**DISCLAIMER:** I've already looked at various approaches to solve my issue, so please read this before labeling this as a duplicate question

I have a javascript running on `https://xyz.com` which has to retrieve information from an application `ABC` running on the user's local machine say port 8080.

My constraints are that I cannot modify the HTTP headers emanating form the `ABC` nor do I want the user to install another application which will be a conduit to route my requests through to `ABC`.

**Cross-Domain/Window Messaging Options**

a) **window.postMessage:** Ruled out since I cannot have script running on the local machine
b) **XDR Object (IE) or Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Firefox,Safari et al):** Ruled out since I cannot modify the header
c) **JSONP:** Again this will not work since I am unable to enclose the response within the function name

As a workaround, only meant for testing I've added the `http://xyz.com` to the trusted list and have enabled `Access Data Across Domains` for sites on this list. AFAIK, this option is only available on IE 5+ browsers. This workaround allows me to send and receive messages from `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
[image]

My question is two-fold
1) If I were to continue with the above approach when I go into production what are the security implications that I'm exposing the user to? Can I plug those holes?
2) Are there any other options that I can pursue to achieve my objective.

**PS:** I would like to be as far away from ActiveX or Flash as possible, but in case that is the only workable alternative to my current approach then I'll have to toe the line

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand, what is your current approach? That that only works for IE?

Comment: Felix, I've added a screenshot of the temporary workaround

Comment: So it is actually not a real workaround as it is only working with IE ;)

Comment: Felix, I guess each browser provides a similar mechanism of disabling cross-domain request validation however I do not want to go down that path.

Answer (score 1):

If the local application could serve a single html document, to act as a bridge, then you could easily use Cross-Document Messaging (for instance with [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net)) together with ajax requests from this document to do this. This is a very simple approach and one commonly used.

easyXDM actually comes with such a document, you can read about it [here](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/).

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll test this and revert

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest would be to put a server script on `https://xyz.com` which will act as a bridge between the javascript file and ABC. Then the javascript file will simply send an AJAX request to it's own server script which will take care of fetching the information from the remote domain. The only other viable solution which would work among most browsers and which doesn't require using some client technology like Flash or ActiveX is JSONP but you have ruled this out because you have no control over the remote domain.

Comment: -1 how is a server script on xyz.com going to access a service running on the clients localhost?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock, what difference does it make? There's a service running on port 8080. Of course if this service is not exposed over the internet only God can access it so the question in this case is meaningless. I guess the OP meant that this 8080 port on the client is accessible from the internet.

Comment: Darin, sorry if I was obtuse, the script running on `https//xyz.com` cannot access the application on user's local machine as the port is not exposed to the internet

Comment: Well then the only option you have is a client scripting technology like Flash or ActiveX.

Comment: Could you answer my first question. If someone is unable to give a suitable alternative, I'd definitely have to go with Flash, ActiveX or a Java Applet:(

Comment: If you enable this option only for trusted sites then it is pretty safe.